Understand AWS Cognito users by sign-in method
I have an application which uses AWS Amplify (Gen 1) for managing users and storing/retrieving data. I'm using Amplify's Auth and API modules - added using amplify add auth and amplify add api.
The packages I'm using are aws-amplify@5.x and @aws-amplify/ui-angular@4.x
I have many existing users already.
I've been asked to add an option for users to login using Microsoft (Entra ID).
I figured moving from the  angular component to the Cognito hosted UI would be the logical option for this. However when I use the hosted UI to sign in an existing Cognito user (not using any external idp), a completely different object is returned {id, name, token} to the app and any API call I try to make returns "no current user". For reference I'm using GraphQL, and storing simple notes, favourites etc.
I assumed I could use Auth.federatedSignIn() to accomplish adding external idps like Microsoft/Google/Facebook etc. While I can sign in and out, again I am returned to the app with a basic token. I cannot understand how to access the api (dynamodb) with the user signed in. Auth.signIn returns a data:CognitoUser. Auth.federatedSignIn returns an object {id, name, token}. I'm sure I'm missing a step to link the token to the CognitoUser, or is there a method I am unaware of that pulls the CognitoUser from Cognito?
Is there a way to get a consistent CognitoUser returned to the app whether I sign in using hosted UI or the amplify-authenticator component. If not, is there any method to take the returned tokens from Cognito and have an object returned just like the Auth.signIn method returns. I understand the sign in methods are different, but it doesn't make sense to me that I cannot access Auth.API when signed in using an idp.
